# What does this following entity exactly means in this PolyMath contract?

Tags: solidity, tokens, presale, airdrop

Here I've added code snippet which is I'm learning right now.

The following terms/ entities/ variable are not understandable why exactly it means and why it is used.
- Founder, Advisor, Bonus1/2/3, Airdrop, Reserve, Presale.

```
uint256 private constant decimalFactor = 10**uint256(18);
enum AllocationType { PRESALE, ADVISOR, FOUNDER, AIRDROP, RESERVE, BONUS1, BONUS2, BONUS3 }

uint256 public constant INITIAL_SUPPLY = 10000000 * decimalFactor;
uint256 public AVAILABLE_TOTAL_SUPPLY = 10000000 * decimalFactor;
uint256 public AVAILABLE_PRESALE_SUPPLY = 30000 * decimalFactor;
uint256 public AVAILABLE_FOUNDER_SUPPLY = 50000 * decimalFactor;
uint256 public AVAILABLE_AIRDROP_SUPPLY = 10000 * decimalFactor;
uint256 public AVAILABLE_ADVISOR_SUPPLY = 20000 * decimalFactor;
uint256 public AVAILABLE_RESERVE_SUPPLY = 2375435 * decimalFactor;
uint256 public AVAILABLE_BONUS1_SUPPLY = 78546 * decimalFactor;
uint256 public AVAILABLE_BONUS2_SUPPLY = 47586 * decimalFactor;
uint256 public AVAILABLE_BONUS3_SUPPLY = 8469840 * decimalFactor;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a type of `enum`, which is a customisable type that is used when there are limited options for a property.
In the example you mentioned from PolyMath, it means that the variable `AllocationType` represents the type of monetary transaction, which could be due to an airdrop event (`AIRDROP`), an investment during presale (`PRESALE`), a special dividend payout for founding members (`FOUNDER`), various types of bonus (`BONUS1`, `BONUS2`, `BONUS3`), etc.

If a transaction is related to advisors, then `AllocationType.ADVISOR` will be used somewhere in the smart contract to store this information.

You could read more about `enum` in the official [Solidity docs](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/types.html#enums).